# Transformation of VC++

Tags: visual-studio-2005

I have a code in VC++ for developing windows through API which runs on Windows NT can this code be edited to run on windows XP.

Every program show only one message Program needs Windows NT to be installed, to run.

Comment: I appreciate that English might not be your first language, but can you clarify the problem you're seeing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If* I understand your problem correctly, the code you're working on most likely checks the version of Windows it's running on. If that's the case, change the version check to include Windows versions later than NT.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestion.